# tinyMCE turning <i> into <em> on getContent

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

in the dom in my tinyMCE editor i see

```
<p>
  <i>testing 123</i>
</p>
```

but when i run

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()
```

it returns

```
<p>
  <em>testing 123</em>
</p>
```

Why is it changing `<i>` into `<em>`? Im having problems with this because i want to insert text dynamically that is surrounded with  tags and things are getting confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [default rule set](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/valid_elements) for the `valid_elements` option contains `em/i` which means that all `<i>` Tags will be replaced by `<em>` in the output. You could add your own `valid_elements` option which would leave `<i>` intact. You could just modify the default rule set for that:

```
valid_elements : "@[id|class|style|title|dir<ltr?rtl|lang|xml::lang|onclick|ondblclick|"
+ "onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|"
+ "onkeydown|onkeyup],a[rel|rev|charset|hreflang|tabindex|accesskey|type|"
+ "name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur],strong/b,em,i,strike,u,"
+ "#p,-ol[type|compact],-ul[type|compact],-li,br,img[longdesc|usemap|"
+ "src|border|alt=|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align],-sub,-sup,"
+ "-blockquote,-table[border=0|cellspacing|cellpadding|width|frame|rules|"
+ "height|align|summary|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],-tr[rowspan|width|"
+ "height|align|valign|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],tbody,thead,tfoot,"
+ "#td[colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|bgcolor|background|bordercolor"
+ "|scope],#th[colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|scope],caption,-div,"
+ "-span,-code,-pre,address,-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-h6,hr[size|noshade],-font[face"
+ "|size|color],dd,dl,dt,cite,abbr,acronym,del[datetime|cite],ins[datetime|cite],"
+ "object[classid|width|height|codebase|*],param[name|value|_value],embed[type|width"
+ "|height|src|*],script[src|type],map[name],area[shape|coords|href|alt|target],bdo,"
+ "button,col[align|char|charoff|span|valign|width],colgroup[align|char|charoff|span|"
+ "valign|width],dfn,fieldset,form[action|accept|accept-charset|enctype|method],"
+ "input[accept|alt|checked|disabled|maxlength|name|readonly|size|src|type|value],"
+ "kbd,label[for],legend,noscript,optgroup[label|disabled],option[disabled|label|selected|value],"
+ "q[cite],samp,select[disabled|multiple|name|size],small,"
+ "textarea[cols|rows|disabled|name|readonly],tt,var,big"
```

Notice I replaced `em/i` with `em,i`. That way both `<i>` and `<em>` are valid tags and neither will be replaced in the output.

If this is too much you could also reduce the list of the valid elements to contain only those elements that you really need in your HTML. For example you might not allow your users to create any tables and therefore you could just remove all references to `table`, `tbody`, `tr`, `td` etc.

Comment: Is there any way to change only the setting that I need i.e. stop conversion from `<i> to <em>` instead of defining all of the settings?

Comment: @RNKushwaha You can use the `extended_valid_elements` property. Any valid element defined here will overwrite the rules in the default rule set. An example would be `extended_valid_elements:"i[id|class|style],em"`